# CORS Allow all on same Server different Ports in JAVA

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, server, cors, port

I have my Project running on **www.example.com:8888**, and my project needs an **API** which is running on the same Server in a different PORT (**www.example.com:8081**). Now I'm facing a **CORS** issue when communicating with the **API**

Below is my JAVA code extract of API:

```
@GET
@Path("/getFiles")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response gettingJsonFiles(@QueryParam("data") String data) throws IOException {
List<org.json.JSONObject> jsonList=JsonService.gettingJsonFiles(data);
return Response.ok(jsonList.toString()).header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT")
.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With")
.allow("OPTIONS").build();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add line `@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:9000")` for allowing Cors

you can create custom filter too - look at -https://howtodoinjava.com/servlets/java-cors-filter-example/

Comment: Thanks for your reply @anshuVersatile
I'm currently not using any frameworks and I'm not able to proceed ! Is there any library available?

Answer (score 0):

Please check in response of CORS request whether your mentioned headers are present.

Please try adding below header along with existing headers:

```
"Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true"
```

Resulting code should be:

```
@GET
@Path("/getFiles")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response gettingJsonFiles(@QueryParam("data") String data) throws IOException 
{
  List<org.json.JSONObject> jsonList=JsonService.gettingJsonFiles(data);
  return Response.ok(jsonList.toString())
   .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
   .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS")
   .header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With")
   .header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
   .build();
}
```

Also if there are any custom headers that you are sending with request, you should add those in `"Access-Control-Allow-Headers"`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Sangam Belose
But I'm still unable to proceed ,When I add this headders the API is not even publically available.Now Its showing 404 Error when requested directly through the browser and earlier it was available.

Comment: 404 should not be the case by adding just these changes..I hope you have restarted the app server.